# Trail shared by bicyclists and hikers

Tags: safety, trails

In my community, there is a new trail for bikers and hikers to share. There are one way arrows for the bikers so they go in one direction. Should the hikers go the same way? I had a bicyclist yell at me for going the wrong way. I thought it would be better to be going the opposite way of the bikes, but I’m not really sure. There are no rules posted about the one-way. The trail is very, very skinny. When I heard the bike, I did completely get off the trail so they could easily pass.

Comment: I don’t know about rules/etiquette, but from a safety perspective it would actually make sense to walk in the opposite direction so you can see approaching cyclists and move out of the way if necessary. I think road rules generally tell you to walk on the left side of the road (for right hand traffic) for the same reason.

Comment: Who built the trail?  They're probably the best people to answer about this specific pathway.

Comment: What country/community? What is the custom where you are? Was it just one cyclist who doesn't understand the rules, or is this a regular occurrence by most/all cyclists you've encountered?

Comment: Great question. As a beginning mountain biker, I have the inverse question - how do I know what trails are ok for biking, and which direction to go? I don't want to bowl anybody over, or make an obstacle out of myself!

Comment: @SamA that would be a good question in its own right *with the location in the question* as the legal position varies a lot

Comment: You had an encounter with a rude cyclist???  I thought those were mythical beings.  Here's [the flip question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/27384) from SE.Great Outdoors - rude hikers on a mixed used trail.  Don't worry overmuch, apply common sense, follow *actual directions posted at trailhead* and ignore Mr/Mrs Having-a-bad-day.

Comment: Funny, @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, I was just about to suggest that this would be one of the _very few_ questions that would be worthy of a cross-post over to [outdoors.se], but you beat me to it!

Comment: Since you didn't mention a location, are you explicitly looking for _non-law_ answers? Would you follow such an answer even if it went against local laws?

Comment: I've had scenarios where an "on your left" warning from behind results in walkers moving to their left into my path. It rarely seems to happen when they see you coming, I would rather have walkers facing me then 5 abreast with a 10 foot dog leash that crosses the trail and going in the same direction.

Comment: @Michael *I don’t know about rules/etiquette, but from a safety perspective it would actually make sense to walk in the opposite direction so you can see approaching cyclists and move out of the way if necessary.*  And when the trail is crowded, how well is that going to work?  **BADLY**.

Comment: @AndrewHenie - IMBA code of conduct says on shared use trails MTBers yield to all other trail users.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: What do you mean? Of course cyclists should always be in control of their vehicle and able to stop in time. But it never hurts to be able to see and react to possible danger. And you’ll have to step out of the way anyway, or how is a cyclist supposed to pass you on a narrow trail?

Comment: @Michael On a crowded trail, with no room to pass, if you're walking *against* bicycle traffic, what happens when a cyclist comes towards you?  You **both** have to stop and maneuver around each other.  If you're walking *with* bicycle traffic, the cyclist just has to go slow and wait behind you until there's an opportunity to pass.  And as noted in another answer, going against traffic significantly increases the closing speed, reducing reaction time.  The claim that walking in the opposite direction as bicycle traffic is safer is dubious.  Trails are **NOT** roads with 40+ kph motor vehicles

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It’s unlikely that the trail is so narrow that you can’t step out of the way. Even on via ferratas one usually finds a way to allow other people to pass (not on bicycles of course). 6km/h walking speed is usually insignificant and you can stop in a single step. Of course if there is a whole crowd of people going uphill (some on bikes, some on foot) it probably makes sense to go with the majority.

Comment: @Michael Your initial comment could easily be an answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135534/discussion-on-question-by-bibliobethica-trail-shared-by-bicyclists-and-hikers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TLDNR: The MTB was ( I will be polite ) outright rude, ignorant and out of line.

Virtually every country has a code of conduct for Mountain bikers, most of these are based on the one the IMBA (International Mountain Bicycling Association) has drawn up.

> 4. Always yield to other trail users. Stop, dismount when near horses. Make your approach known in advance with a bell or soft "hello".

The bikers should have yielded to you unless the local trail has other guidelines.

How this related to single direction tracks- Mountain bike tracks are made single direction because the speed of opposing bikers can lead to dangerous a situations and generally riders on bidirectional tracks have to slow down due to the risk of head on.  A walker generally does not carry the speed of a cyclist (steep uphill excluded) but importantly is far more agile in the event an expected encounter.  To make use that agility, the walker need to be aware, as soon as possible, of the oncoming rider, using both eyes and ears. A walker  going in the same direction as the ride cannot use their eyes, so should be walking in the opposite direction of the cyclists.

However, as a rule, MTB trails are made single direction as a way to allow them to be ridden faster. Usually these are the more technical down hill sections of trail where the rider is free to focus on the ride, not potential a head on, with easier and uphill trails reserved for bi directional travel. MTBers have become used to the idea that a single direction track is permission to ignore the potential of other trail uses they may have presumed they would not cross paths with another trail user.  This is possibly a flaw in the trail design and should be taken up with the owner/authority in charge of the trail.

Comment: "easier *and uphill* trails reserved for bi directional travel" -- hmm, every bi-directional uphill trail is also a downhill trail. Perhaps you just wanted to say "easier trails".

Comment: A hiker is agile but if jumping to the side unexpectedly, it can be extremely dangerous. There is a high probability he will jump where the biker tries to pass him. If there is enough place on the trail, it is much better to stay predictable, maintain ones track and keep the side of trail one was on until the bike is away.

Comment: @naoman - In MTB terms and uphill trail is one used to access the top of the hill to get to the down hill trails. Many down hill trails are not rideable uphill, where as all uphill trails are always rideable down hill.  Many uphill trails are b-directional, usually to allow riders to bypass downhills too technical for them but still sue the trails.   IMBA states that Descending riders yield to climbing riders (obviously on a directional track the rider going in the correct direction has ROW)

Comment: I like the explanation of eyes and ears. Gone are the days of enjoying a peaceful walk on the trail. You really have to be ready for the other trail user that has their ear buds on or eyes on their phone. The best idea I ever learned was when my neighbor got ready to ride out and there was music blaring from his chest. He explained that it's just a bluetooth speaker, but it helps announce his presence. Basically how we're told to make noise to avoid startling bears.

Answer (score 16):

In my experience, there's no rule saying everyone has to go the same direction. Some of my local trails allow cycling in only one direction, and hiking in both. Keep in mind I can't speak for the whole world though; there may be regional customs or other variations.

If the trail is a narrow, downhill path, I would imagine it doesn't matter which way hikers travel because of the difference in speed. From the cyclist's perspective, a hiker would be effectively stationary regardless of whether they are going up or down.

Comment: May matter which side the hikers are looking at but in this case they should travel in the opposite direction than the cyclists.

Comment: Not only looking but also listening – it's easier to locate noises coming from ahead than from behind, and that's typically the more effective warning.

Comment: *I would imagine it doesn't matter which way hikers travel because of the difference in speed.*  Of course it matters - when you're on a bike **behind** a hiker walking in the same direction, you just go slow.  When you're going in opposite directions, both have to stop, and the cyclist likely has to dismount.

Comment: *In my experience, there's no rule saying everyone has to go the same direction.* The trails around me are all "keep right, pass left" for everyone.  As I noted in my previous comment, when trails get crowded mixing directions for cyclists and pedestrians just doesn't work on crowded trails

Comment: Many trails also aren't really official trails, but just paths through the woods. Cycling may or may not be legal depending on various factors (which are country-specific). Itis really impossible to enforce some direction of movement.

Comment: Be aware that a hiker is stationary only until the moment he tries to jump on one side. It may be exactly the side on which the biker planned to pass him!

Comment: @AndrewHenle For a skinny trail like that in the question, somebody's going to have to stop to accommodate the other -- there's no way around it. You're going to have a very lame ride if you're stuck behind a hiker the whole way. In an ideal world, sure, it may be beneficial to have some directionality control, but in real life, one of the parties is going to stopping to let the other pass -- whether they are facing forwards or backwards doesn't really matter in my opinion at that point.

Answer (score 6):

A lot comes down to etiquette, I feel. It's hardly something that can really be enforced if you think about it; other than some users potentially getting irritated at you. But that's often modern life sadly at the best of times.

In my part of the world I occasionally follow 'designated' walk trails on my bike through some areas just for the sake of variety, BUT I am conscious of that it is for walkers first, so I exercise due caution and drop a bit of speed to allow for someone appearing around a blind corner etc.

Similarly, I don't mind seeing walkers or hikers on designated bike or cross-country riding trails either - as long as they're cognisant it is a bike trail, and they remain alert and aware there are faster moving users and yield to them off the path when we're heard approaching.  Making an effort to be visible in brighter clothing would help too.

Bear in mind also people may sound angrier when they're pumped full of adrenalin, huffing and puffing. It may sound like a big personal affront if they yell at you. Think of a warning shout as a more primal version of a bicycle bell and just shrug it off.

There's probably a few other factors too. I wouldn't ride a walk trail during good weather on a public holiday for instance where there's likely to more walkers than usual. Similarly, if it's a busy bike trail I'd avoid it on foot because you'd be likely spending more of your time jumping out of the way than enjoying the stroll.

Comment: I know the question is a bit buried, but this dosn't really answer it.

Comment: @Clumsycat I'd say this answers it. The question is "Should the hikers go the same way (as the cyclists)?" The answer given here is "A lot comes down to etiquette," followed by some personal practices, preferences, and situational examples.

Answer (score 6):

If the arrows are expressly labeled as being for cyclists, I'd say that it implies that hikers can go whichever way they prefer. Venturing a guess, the direction is probably mandated for cyclists to prevent them from colliding with one another more than out of concern for them colliding with hikers.

As far as which is safer, as others have mentioned it's generally considered safer on normal roads for pedestrians to move against traffic. However, that doesn't necessarily translate to trails where cyclists are the fastest moving users.

The main concern is the speeds at which users approach one another, sometimes referred to as "closing speed." When two users approach one another, their closing speed is their two speeds added together. When they are moving in the same direction, the closing speed is the chaser's speed minus the chasee's speed.

An average cyclist moves at about 15 mph. An average hiker moves at 3 mph. Where things get complicated is if you throw joggers in the mix, who move at an average of about 6 mph.

This table represents the closing speeds of average cyclists, joggers, and hikers when the users on the left are approaching the users in the top row and they are both moving in the same direction.

|  | Cyclist | Jogger | Hiker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Cyclist** | 0 | 9 | 12 |
| **Jogger** | * | 0 | 3 |
| **Hiker** | * | * | 0 |

* These are technically negative. In other words, the user in the left column  will never catch the user in the top row. If they were on a circular track, the user on the top would eventually come around and lap the user on the left.

This table represents the closing speeds of the same users, but when they are approaching one another from opposite directions.

|  | Cyclist | Jogger | Hiker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Cyclist** | 30 | 21 | 18 |
| **Jogger** | 21 | 12 | 9 |
| **Hiker** | 18 | 12 | 6 |

As you can see from the two tables, closing speeds are *much* higher for users who are approaching one another. And in contrast to what others answers say about a hiker being "effectively stationary" from a cyclist's perspective, there is a pretty drastic difference in closing speeds for hikers moving in the same direction as cyclists vs. in opposite directions.

It's certainly true that moving in the opposite direction of cyclists will allow you to see them and move out of the way faster, but it also gives both parties less time to respond to one another. And if you decide to jog a little, that difference really becomes pretty drastic pretty quickly.

What's more, hikers and joggers moving in both directions actually creates more opportunities for impact due to a higher number of times that users pass one another. When traveling in the same direction, passing a faster moving user is impossible and passing a user who is moving at close to the same speed is exceedingly rare. When they're moving in opposite directions, it's commonplace. If the trail is circular and faster users are doing laps, they'll pass slower moving users *much* more frequently if they're moving in the same direction.

All in all, it's a judgment call on whether that additional reaction time of seeing approaching cyclists is enough to offset the loss in reaction time due to higher closing speeds compounded with a greater number of impact opportunities. You need to balance the local conditions of the trail (lines of sight, ability to move freely, whether or not people are doing laps, etc.) with the mathematical realities of the closing speeds.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes bikers are so fast and quiet that it's hard to hear them until they're almost upon you.  Safety first: walk in the opposite direction.  In that way, you can see fast-moving bikers coming towards you and react accordingly.  Accident prevention protects both you and bikers; they should appreciate that.

Comment: Not legal on many trails.  For example:  https://www.wodfriends.org/accessibility/safety/  And on a crowded trail, walking against traffic will cause all kinds of problems - cyclists will have to stop and probably dismount, and then that will block everyone.

Comment: *In that way, you can see fast-moving bikers coming towards you and react accordingly.* Also, as the answer by @jimchristie states, when you go the opposite direction you increase the closing speed dramatically.  How is that any safer?  Are there any blind turns or hills on that trail?  Where most others are walking *with* bicycle traffic?  That's not safer, not at all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I didn't see anything on that page about illegal to walk in the opposite direction to bikers.  I suggest creating an answer promoting your view, especially one with more specific references to clear rules about directionality.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the trail rules are arbitrary: it may make no real sense. However, one way bike trails may be to prevent erosion: a downhill track cause braking ruts and bumps, or a steep climb requires more torque.

But it may be easier for the hikers to navigate knowing bikes are coming in only one direction.

I would certain respect these rules either way. For all you know, it was a long negotiation to permit bikes on these trails and riding illegally may lose access for all.